Does AWS S3 trigger a Lambda function once for multiple lifecycle expiration events or for each object?
I'm writing a Lambda function that is triggered by an S3 bucket using the LIFECYCLE_EXPIRATION event. The primary purpose of this function is to handle the deletion of database metadata records corresponding to objects that expire due to lifecycle policies.
For example, let's say I have a scenario where 100,000 objects in the S3 bucket are set to expire today. My question is:
Will all 100,000 objects be sent as part of a single event notification, resulting in one Lambda invocation with 100,000 records in the event['Records'] JSON? Or will S3 trigger the Lambda function 100,000 times, once for each object being deleted?
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventTime": "2024-10-18T12:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "DeleteObject",
      "s3": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": "my-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "object1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventTime": "2024-10-18T12:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "DeleteObject",
      "s3": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": "my-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "object2"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventTime": "2024-10-18T12:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "DeleteObject",
      "s3": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": "my-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "object100000"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


The invocation payload size limit for a Lambda function invocation is 6MB. I would expect, but do not know for sure, that the invoking service will batch records for efficiency while ensuring that the aggregate does not exceed the payload size limit.

is there any specific need why you are using lambda function for this? i have worked with lifecycle configuration rules, and the expired objects end up being deleted anyways. They might still appear in the console for some time, but at the end, they are deleted. Be mindful, that there is a minum storage duration that you are being charge for (usually 30 days minimun).

@FranciscoParrilla The primary purpose of this function is to handle the deletion of database metadata records corresponding to objects that expire due to lifecycle policies.
